# Identifing a connector pair

Tags: connector, identification, low-power, low-voltage

Male part on the board:

[image]

Female part in the casing, on the cable. Lockable.

[image][image][image]

What type of connectors are these?

---

Sorry for low quality photos, camera seems to be incapable to do macro job. But male image is lucky one, and 24 conductors are more or less recognisable on it. I examined a female part and can positively confirm, connector have 24 conductors (not counting outer casing, which might be used as an additional "ground" conductor).

Comment: Just for a bit of extra context it might be worth mentioning what the connector is used for and see if you can count how many pins it has.

Comment: @PeterJ, I thought pin number was obvious from the male image, it have 24. I'd prefer to not disassemble it until I have some information on spare parts.

Comment: @user539484 What device is the main board? Mobile phone? Which model number?

Answer (score 1):

I believe what this connector is *older*(!) 24-pin so called [**cellular phone dock connector**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_external_power_supply#Charger_and_interface_standard_in_South_Korea) compliant to *older* [TTAS.KO-06.0028/R2](http://www.tta.or.kr/include/Download.jsp?filename=stnfile/TTA-0044.pdf) Korean national standard.

## Important!

I emphasized *older* because this TTAS.KO-06.0028/R2 standard has been superseded by [TTAS.KO-06.0028/R4](http://www.tta.or.kr/include/Download.jsp?filename=stnfile/TTAS.KO-06.0028R4_e13.pdf) which have 20 pins instead of 24.